# Android add custom attribute to styles

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a feature to let the user change the theme.

I've done this but depending on if the theme is light or dark, I need to use the opposite color to draw line on a canvas. I thought the best way to do this would be to simply call R.style.colorAttribute to get the correct color when doing the drawing.

In the styles.xml I have defined the following themes:

```
<style name="DarkTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />

<style name="LightTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />
```

Can anyone help on the best way to add an attribute here which will store the color. I've not done this before and was n't sure if I should use the color.xml file or the styles.xml file.

Thanks

And just to make it clear

I for the dark theme I need a white color
and for the light them I need the same attribute but in black.

Comment: Why don't you use the inverse color attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you like a theme, but want to tweak it, just add the theme as the parent of your custom theme. For example, you can modify the traditional light theme to use your own color like this:

```
<color name="custom_theme_color">#b0b0ff</color>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

[More about styles on developer.android.com.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: Yes, but instead of using an android attribute such as `android:windowBackground` can't I define my own to save the color.

I don't want to change any attributes, I just need to call the same attribute whether it's a light or dark theme.

It's not such a big issue, I could just use if statements in the code to check which color to use, I thought it would have been nice to do it here.